# Getting Shibboleth Attributes through Struts-1

Tags: java, struts, httprequest, struts-1, shibboleth

I'm trying to integrate Shibboleth authentication with an old Struts-1 application that I've inherited the maintenance of, but I cannot figure out how to acecss the Shibboleth attributes.

This is what I have tried:

```
public final class AuthenticateAction extends MappingDispatchAction {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {


        Enumeration attributeNames = request.getAttributeNames();
        while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String attributeNm = (String) attributeNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println("DEBUG: " + attributeNm);
        }

        String eppn = (String) request.getAttribute("eppn"); // <-- Null
```

None of the Shibboleth attributes that I expect are printed out while looping through the attribute names in the code above.

How do I access the Shibboleth attributes?

Comment: Wouldn't they be in the session?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I also tried looping and printing the attribute names from `request.getSession().getAttributeNames()` and could not find the attributes I was looking for.

Comment: In the action you posted, are you authenticated yet? A security framework won't store anything until the user is authenticated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I am authenticated.

Comment: TBH, I don't know `shibboleth`, but some other web security frameworks  I've used use their own session management. You might have access to it with some static class through `ThreadLocal`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my case, it was an issue with the server-side config.

After following the instructions here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall, I was able to get the attributes simply as:

`String eppn = (String) request.getAttribute("eppn"); // <-- no longer null`

Comment: what did you do?